# What is the correct way to reference variables in terraform? When to use interpolation ${var.} and when to directly call var.?

Tags: variables, terraform

I am new to Terraform. I have a doubt regarding referencing variable in the main.tf file.

Is it ami = var.image or ami = "${var.image}". What is the difference, when to use directly
var. and when to use interpolation ${var.}

Example:

```
variable "instancetype" {
    default = "t2.micro"
}

variable "image" {
    default = "ami-<ami id>"
}

resource "aws_instance" "new"{
    ami = var.image
    instance_type = var.instancetype

tags = {
    Name = "New-Instance"
}
}
```

Comment: Older versions of terraform used the interpolation syntax always. Newer versions do not require interpolation to be used. Interpolation is usually required with string concatenation and other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `${var.example}` syntax is for including the result of an expression into a larger string. It is part of [Terraform's string template syntax](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#string-templates). For example, you might write `"${var.example}-foo"` to produce a string that consists of the value of `var.example` followed by the literal suffix `-foo`.

If you need only the value of the variable in isolation, without concatenating it with any other string values, there is no reason to use that interpolation syntax; `var.example` and `"${var.example}"` are exactly equivalent.

For simple situations that Terraform can understand via basic syntactic analysis, [`terraform fmt`](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/fmt) will replace a redundant expression like `"${var.example}"` with its simpler equivalent `var.example`. That tool encodes various idiomatic style conventions like this, and so it can be useful to apply the result of that tool (either directly by running it, or via its integration into plugins for editors like Visual Studio Code) to see if it makes an adjustment that would make your configuration style consistent with the usual idiomatic style.